# Call multiple functions in React, one inside and another outside a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a trigger that is supposed to change a state of its child component. The results of both render statements are inconsequential. My only concern here is that I am unsure how to use the `trigger` trigger to call the `leftbehind` function without putting `leftbehind` inside its parent render `Another`.

My code is below. The goal is to have `leftbehind` run without having to put it inside the render.

```
var Another = React.createClass({
  leftbehind: function() {
    if (this.props.status === "dare") {
      alert('Winning!');
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    if (this.props.status === "truth") {
      return (<p>Yes</p>);
    } else {
      return (<p>Nope</p>);
    }
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function() {
    return {deesfault: "truth"};
  },
  trigger: function() {
    this.setState({deesfault: "dare"});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div> 
        <p onClick={this.trigger}>{this.state.deesfault}</p>
        <Another status={this.state.deesfault}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The reason I do not want to place `leftbehind` inside the render, is because it is technically supposed to take the place of an API call. And I do not want that to be called inside the render function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation executes `leftbehind` each time `<Another>` is rendering with its `status` prop being `true`. That said, once `status` is flipped to `true`, `leftbehind` will be executed over and over in every following rendering until it is flipped back to `false`. This will seriously cause problems.

Since the intention is to trigger `leftbehind` with a click event, I would restructure the components in different ways.

- Move `leftbehind` into the parent component and have it executed along with the click event. If `<Another>` needs the results, passed them on through props.

  ```
  var Another = React.createClass({
    render() {
      return <div>{this.props.params}</div>;
    }
  });

  var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      return {apiRes: null};
    },
    onClick() {
      const res = someAPICall();
      this.setState({apiRes: res});
    },
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <p onClick={this.onClick}>Fire</p>
          <Another params={this.state.apiRes} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
  ```
- Or, move the `<p>` element into `<Another>` along with the click event.

  ```
  var Another = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
      return {apiRes: null};
    },
    onClick() {
      var res = someAPICall();
      this.setState({apiRes: res});
    },
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <p onClick={this.onClick}>Fire</p>
          <div>{this.state.apiRes}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  var App = function() { return <Another />; }
  ```

In the latter, the key logic is handled in the inner component. The outer one is just a container. In the former one, the outer component handles the logic and pass on the results if any. It depends on how the components relate with the API call to decide which suits better. Most importantly, in both cases the API will not execute unless the click event is triggered.